# In which method should I set the delegate of a UITextField?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is it good practice to be setting the delegate of a UITextField in viewDidLoad or in an init method?
I tried setting the delegate as self in an init method, but it wasn't calling the corresponding delegate methods, when I moved the code into viewDidLoad, it registered as setting self as the delegate?
It seems that I should be able to set it in either method, if someone can help clear this up for me it would be much appreciated.

```
-(id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) 
        textField.delegate = self;     //this text field is an IBOutlet
        //some other code here as well
    return self;
}
```

OR

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    textField.delegate = self;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your text field is an `IBOutlet` then until `viewDidLoad` method is called your text field will be `nil` (hence you set delegate to `nil` object). When `viewDidLoad` gets called it literally means that view was loaded and all IBOutlets and IBActions were connected and are at your disposal.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your class is a UIViewController and is loaded from a NIB (since you have an IBOutlet), the proper init method to override is `initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)decoder`. What's happening right now:

1. iOS loads your NIB file and creates your UIViewController
2. The UIViewController is created by calling its `initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)decoder` method.
3. The first thing that `initWithCoder` does is to call `init` and therefore your code, **before it has even decoded the NIB**.
4. Because it hasn't decoded the NIB yet, your `textField` IBOutlet hasn't been set yet (if you debug it you should be able to see that its value is nil inside your `init`). And therefore setting the delegate doesn't do anything.

The easiest way to proceed is indeed to set your delegate in the `viewDidLoad` method; it can't be done in `init`. However it **can** be done by overriding `initWithCoder`:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)decoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:decoder];
    if (self)
        textField.delegate = self;
    return self;
}
```

This time you wait until UIViewController's implementation of `initWithCoder` has finished decoding the NIB and so all your outlets have been set.

Comment: Which is most compliant of iOS standards? Should I set the delegate in viewDidLoad or in initWithCoder?

Comment: You should most definitely set your delegate in `viewDidLoad` since controller's view may get unloaded when your app receives memory warning and your outlet will be lost (at least it should be unset in `viewDidUnload`.