# Why can't I set the delegates of these UITextFields when the ViewController is being initialized?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
-(id) initForNewItem{
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"EmployeeDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    if(self){
        [nameField setDelegate:self];
        [pinField setDelegate:self];
    }
    return self;
}
```

In this case, the delegates are not successfully set. However, if I go into the xib file and ctrl-click + drag the UITextFields onto the file owner and set them as delegates through that, it works. Can someone explain why calling setter methods in the init method does not work?

Comment: If your text field is an IBOutlet then until viewDidLoad method is called your text field will be nil (hence you set delegate to nil object). When viewDidLoad gets called it literally means that view was loaded and all IBOutlets and IBActions were connected and are at your disposal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062475/in-which-method-should-i-set-the-delegate-of-a-uitextfield

Answer (score 0):

Inside init method, the views haven't been loaded. All the visual setup must be done further on in the viewController's lifecycle, at least into the viewDidLoad method. Or in case that you don't go for a .xib solution, you can do it while loading the view manually, into the loadView method.

So, both labels are nil into the init method, and the delegate can't be set.